# Access a static file saved inside the WEB-INF folder of a Servlet from the doPost() method

Tags: image, google-app-engine, servlets, blob

I'm trying to access some images that I have saved in my Servlet inside the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/imgs` folder, this way:
[link](http://postimg.org/image/obsolifx7/)

I tryed to access these images with this code within the `doPost` method of my `Servlet`:

```
InputStream s = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("http://cardimgs.org/imgs/cardbackground1.jpg");

Movie movie = new Movie();
try {
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(s);
    movie.setImage(bytes);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
try {
    // Store the image in App Engine's datastore
    pm.makePersistent(movie);
} finally {
    pm.close();
}
```

`Movie` class: 
[link 2](http://pastie.org/private/75ufhdfyadqey1c7ubt3w),

the reason why I used the specified `url`to create the `InputStream` is because in my `appengine-web.xml` I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>myApplicationId</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
    </system-properties>
    <static-files>
        <include path="/**.jpg"/>

        <include path="/imgs" >
            <http-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://cardimgs.org" />
        </include>
    </static-files>


</appengine-web-app>
```

where I try to define my static files.

**My problem is**, though, that with the above code I can't access my file and fill the `InputStream`, which appears to be `null`, therefore returning a `NullPointerException`.

How can I successfully access my static files?

Comment: Read the javadoc of ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(): it loads resources using the *class loader*. It thus looks for them in *the classpath*. The classpath is constitued from WEB-INF/classes and from all the jars inside WEB-INF/lib. And the path it expects looks like `com/mycompany/myproject/somefile.txt`. It can't be a http URL. What you need is ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/imgs/cardbackground1.jpg")

Comment: ok, I have tried this way: 
`InputStream s = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/imgs/cardbackground1.jpg");` but didn't work. Does the `<include path>` attribute still count? I've updated it this way anyway: `<static-files>
        <include path="WEB-INF/imgs/*.jpg"/></static-files>`

Comment: It didn't work because, as I said in my previous comment, the classpath doesn't contain the root of your webapp. It contains WEB-INF/classes and all the jars inside WEB-INF/lib. So, as I also said in my previous comment, you need ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/imgs/cardbackground1.jpg").

Comment: Nice!! thank you... you haven't added an answer though. If you'll do so, I will accept it.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` loads resources using *the class loader**. It thus looks for them in **the classpath**. The classpath of a web-app is constitued from `WEB-INF/classes` and from all the jars inside `WEB-INF/lib`. The path it expects looks like com/mycompany/myproject/somefile.txt. It can't be a HTTP URL.

What you need is `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/imgs/cardbackground1.jpg")`. This method loads a resource from anywhere inside the web-app.